# Bootstrap 3 tablet portrait menu

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

After doing some research I found out our bootstrap website isn't working propperly on the iPad when  viewing it in portrait mode. Our menu is under our brand.

How can I use the `@grid-float-breakpoint` after 778px?

[This is whats troubling us](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mm2XR.png)

Comment: Is it the same on a desktop when we resize the windows? Can you supply a link?

Comment: Hi @Romain yes, it's the same when I resize the window on a desktop. Link is http://dreamix-studio.com/ . Thanks!

Comment: Can you share an image of your wanted menu on Ipad portrait? I can code it for you but I need to understand what you really want. http://www.responsinator.com/?url=http://www.dreamix-studio.com/&device=ipad-portrait. I modify the police to fit the menu  new_style.css line 514 .nav > li > a {
font-size: 12px;} it will display your menu in one line
}

Comment: Hi @Romain, http://www.dreamix-studio.com/robin/badstrap.png . This is whats going on right now and it should work like your link (just a navbutton on the right).

Comment: Can you send me a design of the result that you want for the ipad portrait? I don't really understand what you want =(

Comment: Just like your editor showed our site:): http://dreamix-studio.com/robin/badstrap2.png .

Comment: Ok, I don't have the same result has you on my link, this is why =)